# Subscribe to child Observable's Subscribe in RxJS

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I have `emitEvenFrom` method that takes one argument and emits the event.

when the argument is false it doesn't emit any event though am directly returning an observable of type `of`.

```js
import { Observable, Observer, of } from 'rxjs'

function emitEventFrom(thisObservable: boolean): Observable<string> {
    return Observable.create(function (observer: Observer<String>) {
        if (thisObservable) {
          observer.next('thisObservable')
          observer.complete()
        } else {
          // Returning Rx.Observable.of()
          return of('Other observable')
        }
    })
}

emitEventFrom(false).subscribe({
    next: (value) => console.log(value),
    error: (error) => console.log(error)
})
```

Why the subscribe ins't called on `of` Observable when I have returned it.

Instead I have to subscribe to the that observable explicitly and pass on the event to the parent observable then only it works. Doing this it increases the code that I have write.

```js
function emitEventFrom(thisObservable: boolean): Observable<string> {
    return Observable.create(function (observer: Observer<String>) {
        if (thisObservable) {
            observer.next('thisObservable')
            observer.complete()
        } else {
            // Returning Rx.Observable.of()
            of('Other observable').subscribe({
                next: (value) => observer.next(value),
                error: (error) => observer.error(error)
            })
        }
    })
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? or Show me a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return `of` from your function instead of inside of `Observable.create`

Here is a working [blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-duuxrr?file=index.ts)

Change your `emitEventFrom` to following

```js
function emitEventFrom(thisObservable: boolean): Observable<string> {
  if (thisObservable) {
    return Observable.create(function (observer: Observer<String>) {
      observer.next('thisObservable')
      observer.complete();
    });
  } else {       
    return of('Other observable');
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you give me an example? Or better a stackblitz? So I can work on that

Comment: I have uploaded my code to https://gist.github.com/anirudhamahale/8e8ee2707e3a2870a0f9fa1b95ef1d69, I can't upload it on stackblitz since it contains connections of db.